# How do I get a Luis top-scoring intent from a TextPrompt in a Waterfall (Bot Framework v4)

Tags: botframework

I'm using a TextPrompt in a waterfall dialog (Microsoft Bot Framework v4, node.js) to ask a user a question. I see in the emulator that Luis Trace is returning a recognizerResult which contains the top-scoring intent, but how do I access it and act upon it?

Example steps:

```
async askAQuestionStep(step) {
  return await step.prompt(MYQUESTION_PROMPT, {
    prompt: 'How are you feeling?'
  });
}
async getAnAnswerStep(step) {
  if (step.result) {
    if (topScoringIntent === 'Good') {
      await step.context.sendActivity("Good to hear.");
  } else {
    return await step.next();
  }
}
```

Need to figure out how to actually access "topScoringIntent." The [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=js) show how to do this, but I'm getting this error:

```
[onTurnError]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'recognize' of undefined
```

I'm not calling this from bot.js, but from its own dialog/file.

Comment: have you tried setting a breakpoint and seeing what is being returned?

Comment: I'm trying to follow the example [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=js) but I'm getting this error: "[onTurnError]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'recognize' of undefined" -- I'm also calling this in a separate dialog/file, not from bot.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer: [Getting the Luis "topIntent" from a child dialog inside another file (Node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53232536/getting-the-luis-topintent-from-a-child-dialog-inside-another-file-node-js)

I had to create a luisRecognizer in the dialog file and then pass the botConfig, userSate and conversationState to the dialog.

Comment: A byproduct of this approach for my particular bot: it makes two calls to the Luis endpoint: the first one from bot.js, the second from the child dialog--every time I get "topIntent" from a child dialog.