# Getting the Luis "topIntent" from a child dialog inside another file (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have Luis working in my main bot.js file for top level intents. But i'd like to access Luis from other dialogs that are in their own files, called by bot.js:

bot.js:

```
const { InitialDialog } = require('./dialogs/initial');    
const INITIAL_DIALOG = 'initialDialog';
const START_INTENT = 'Start';
```

then in the bot's class:

```
this.dialogs.add(
    new InitialDialog(
        INITIAL_DIALOG,
        this.userProfileAccessor,
        botConfig
    )
);
```

and finally, if the "Start intent" is detected we start the dialog:

```
await dc.beginDialog(InitialDialog);
```

In dialogs/initial/index.js:

```
class Initial extends ComponentDialog {
    constructor(dialogId, userProfileAccessor, botConfig) {
 super(dialogId);
}
```

Here's where it gets problematic: when I try and call Luis:

```
// Perform a call to LUIS to retrieve results for the user's message.

const results: RecognizerResult = await this.luisRecognizer.recognize(turnContext);

// Since the LuisRecognizer was configured to include the raw results, get the `topScoringIntent` as specified by LUIS.
const topIntent = results.luisResult.topScoringIntent;
```

I'm getting an error:

```
[onTurnError]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'recognize' of undefined
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **luisRecognizer** needs to be created:

```
    const luisApplication = {
        applicationId: luisConfig.appId,
        endpointKey: luisConfig.subscriptionKey || luisConfig.authoringKey,
        endpoint: luisConfig.getEndpoint()
    };

    // Create configuration for LuisRecognizer's runtime behavior.
    const luisPredictionOptions = {
        includeAllIntents: true,
        log: true,
        staging: false
    };

this.luisRecognizer = new LuisRecognizer(luisApplication, luisPredictionOptions , true);
```

A sample using LUIS can be found here: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/12.nlp-with-luis

Comment: So, I have the luisRecognizer in my main bot.js file -- do I need to include it again in initial.js?

Comment: I don't know what your project file structure is.  Is the project in a public repository?  Can you share more of the code?

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer, as it is indeed correct and fixed my problem! If you have multiple dialogs in separate files, it appears you need to use a luisRecognizer in each file (would allow you to use different Luis endpoints, or pass each dialog the same botConfig, userState and conversationState, etc.). Thanks!